# Bivariate Skewness algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics, normal-distribution

I wonder if anyone can help me on my interpretion of the algorithm that allow to compute the bivariate skewness which is a univariate measure of skewness for bivariate data.
The bivariate skewness is defined as described in this paper:

http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2346576?sid=21105063910471&uid=3737592&uid=4&uid=2

I considered p =2(bivariate) and took the same other assumptions as described in the paper.
Here is the function I wrote to compute b1,p (algorithm of Skewness in the paper) in python:

```
def multiSkew(x1, x2): #bivariate function, e.g use two columns of dataframe (same len)
    covariance_x1_x2 = np.cov(x1,x2) # compute the covariance matrix
    inv_covariance_x1_x2 = np.linalg.inv(covariance_x1_x2) #inverse of covariance mat
    x1_x2_mean = np.mean(x1),np.mean(x2) #mean value of each variable
    mk = []
    for x_i in x1:
        for y_i in x2:
            x_diff = x_i - x1_x2_mean[0] #from the equation(see link) (xi-xbar)
            y_diff = y_i - x1_x2_mean[1] # (xj-xbar)
            yj = np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(x_diff),inv_covariance_x1_x2),y_diff)
            mk.append(yj**3)
    skew=(1.0/(len(x1)**2))*sum(mk)
    return skew
```

I have this when I tested it
My Skewness is too big. It normally should turn around zero if I am right

```
In: multiSkew(x1,x2)
Out[15]: 2809276168.079186
```

Can anyone, more advanced in programming ,help me please?I should have made an error somewhere in the summing part.

I don't think that there is a python module that can help me to compute the skewness of a multivariate set of data.In scipy, the skew module is just for univariate set of data by the way.

Comment: Should `mk = []` be reset within the `for x_i in x1` loop?  ...you're continually appending to this array.

Comment: I diid it in order to store for each observation in x1 (or x2) the value computed in a list and then I sum each of them.
What's your opinion about it? I am interrested in what you will come up with :)

Comment: I can't help you with the algorithm in other respects, but I don't think you're calculating the sum you want correctly. I think the final `skew` calc should be: `skew=(1.0/(len(x1)**2))*sum(mk)`.  You want to sum over all the observations.  You're currently including sums from earlier observations many times with your: `ya=sum(mk) then y.append(ya)`.  (alternatively, as I mentioned in prev comment, you could just reset the mk array each time through since you've already saved off its sum in `y`).

Comment: I corrected the code following your remark but still having too high value. I also corrected in yj the transposed x_diff.
I am still having difficulties to find my way. skew is too high:)